# wait to asynctask finish from another asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, wait

im doing a query to a DB with an asyntask which works into an object, and im creating this object into an asyntask. Problem is that i dont know how to wait for the query result before trying to use methods from this object.It causes null pointer exception. I tried with this while and it works but, i know its not properly done.

```
//with this constructor i create an asyntask which does the query to the db 
empresa = new Empresa(id_empresa);

/*while(!empresa.consulta_terminada){
    //no hagas nada mientras la empresa este en consulta
}*/

Log.e("EMPRESA NOMBRE", empresa.getNombre());

cita = new Cita(itinerario,hora_formato,empresa);
citas.add(cita);
```

Sorry for my english and Thanks!

Comment: Where are you executing the AsyncTask?

Comment: im executing the first asynctask in an activity, into that one im creating the object Empresa which has a method to do another asynctask.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass a Runnable to the AsyncTask, and invoke it at postExecute().
or use Handler and HandlerThread to do async tasks, it will be more flex.